# droid2 mp4 playback issue

Tags: android, video, mp4

I have a problem playing mp4 video files on the Droid2 with android 2.2 (build VZW) . The app tries to play the videos from the sdcard and the it takes for ever and doesnt load the video.

I tried to debug the app on the phone with adb. When I play the video it give the below decoding error on the logcat:

TIOMX_CORE: dlopen libOMX.TI.720P.Decoder.so failed because Cannot load library: load_library[1083]: Library 'libOMX.TI.720P.Decoder.so' not found

1134  2189 D         : error 0x80001003 in DoPrepare

1134  2189 V PlayerDriver: HandleInformationalEvent: PVMFInfoErrorHandlingStart

1134  2189 V PlayerDriver: HandleInformationalEvent: type=26 UNHANDLED

2103  2109 W MediaPlayer: info/warning (1, 26)

1134  2190 D OMX_AACDEC: AACDEC_ComponentThread():150 150 :: Comp Thrd Exiting here..

1134  2189 D OMX_AACDEC: ComponentDeInit():1726 :: Freeing: pComponentPrivate = 0x60af8

1134  2189 D TIOMX_CORE: Found matching pHandle(0x5db70) at index 7 with refCount 1

1134  2189 D         : enter SharedLibraryLookup

1134  2189 D         : enter GetFactoryAndMimeString

1134  2189 V PlayerDriver: CommandCompleted

1134  2189 V PlayerDriver: Completed command PLAYER_PREPARE status=PVMFErrResource

1134  2189 E PlayerDriver: Command PLAYER_PREPARE completed with an error or info PVMFErrResource

1134  2189 V PVPlayer: check_for_live_streaming s=-2147483648, cancelled=0

1134  2189 V PlayerDriver: HandleInformationalEvent: PVMFInfoErrorHandlingComplete

1134  2189 W PlayerDriver: PVMFInfoErrorHandlingComplete

2103  2108 E MediaPlayer: error (1, -17)

I assume that 2.2 has some decoder issues playing the mp4 files. Did any one run into this issue. I am not sure how to nail this one. Might be an option to upgrade the 2.2 to 2.2.1 or 2.2.2 or 2.3?

I would really appreciate if anyone can shed some light on this one.

Thanks,
Raja.

Comment: Found the issue. The input mp4 file was encoded with H264 version high. But, Android specifically mentions that it should be a baseline versions. Works after the version change. Phew!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there is another reason.

```
Library 'libOMX.TI.720P.Decoder.so' not found
```

I.e. the file was removed from it's location, thanks to a patch that came sometime prior to November 2010.

The solution:

**1.Download These files from the [Liberty Rom Source](https://bitbucket.org/JRummy16/liberty-rom/src) repo:**

in /system/lib:

```
libOMX.TI.720P.Decoder.so
libOMX.TI.720P.Encoder.so
libOMX.TI.mp4.splt.Encoder.so
```

in /system/lib/dsp/

```
720p_h264vdec_sn.dll64P
720p_mp4vdec_sn.dll64P
720p_mp4venc_sn.dll64P
```

2.Using Root Manager or any other file explorer **mount system as R/W**

Copy the six files into "/system/lib/" and "/system/lib/dsp/", respectively, on your phone,

3.**change permissions to 644 (rw-r--r--)**

4.**Remount system back to R/O (Read Only)**

5.**Reset**

6.**Go play** any 720p video on the stock video player and stop getting "Sorry this video cannot be played" errors!

[Source](http://www.droidforums.net/forum/droid-2-general-discussions/95330-m4v-playback-busted-after-update.html#post982329)

Comment: Thanks Steve. Good to know this. Will try this one.